Split out numbers in a column
I'm trying to split out the two numbers in the cell into separate columns
I've tried "text to columns", using the delimitator "space" but it removes the second number in each of the cells  leaving me with only the first number.
enter image description here

Not sure what you did, but it works on my end, please see Demo:
Demo




Select the range.
From Data Tab --> First Step --> Delimited --> Next
Second Step --> Delimiters as Space --> Next
Third Step --> Column Data Format --> Kept as Text you can also keep it General
Finish.


Or Use TEXTSPLIT()
=TEXTSPLIT(A2," ")


Or Single Array formula:
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(" "&A2:A24," ",{1,2})," ")


